# Best rock climbing places near Paris (France)

Tags: paris, mountain-climbing

What are the best places to rock climb around Paris?

Comment: What does 'best' mean in this context? The nearest? The most popular? The cheapest? The best looking girls?  It's got the potential to be a great question but right now it's too thinly composed.  Lack of distinct focus.  Close voting as 'opinion based'

Comment: Also, how far around Paris are you expecting to go ? 1 hour, 3 hours?

Comment: “Best” needs qualification. That being said, there's one main place where Parisians go rock climbing for the day: [the Forest of Fontainebleau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontainebleau_rock_climbing).